Why does this LC VCO work without varactor but becomes really noisy as soon as I add the varactors?
I am trying to design an LC VCO in TSMC's 65nm CMOS process. First I designed an LC oscillator without any tuning i.e. I used MIM capacitors which are included with the PDK as well as inductors from the PDK, the design seemed to work and hence, I added 2 varactors in parallel so to be able to tune it a little bit.
I was trying to design the VCO for 5 GHz. For the initial LC Oscillator I had chosen a 147pH inductor whose quality factor was roughly 30 and a capacitor whose value is 6.4pF, this gives me oscillations of around 5.12GHz.

Here for my initial LC Oscillator the parameters are as follows : Vdd = 1.2v,L=60n,W =1ux50 (i.e. I have 50 fingers), Ibias = 5mA.
The output for this initial LC Oscillator is :
With the same parameters, I added the varactors with control voltage in the middle, parallel to my LC tanks :
And now when I tried running transient simulation, I am not getting a "stable" periodic waveform, instead I am getting a random noisy output.
Here is the noisy output for this VCO now:
As for the varactors, I plotted their characteristic (for around 5GHz) using S-parameter analysis and some math which came out to be as follows :

Could anyone please explain to me what am I doing wrong? The output after addition of these varactors doesn't resemble a periodic waveform at all.

It would help if you included all mentioned simulation results. Try putting a short (e.g. 1 ns) pulsed current source in parallel with one of the transistor drains. Sometimes, oscillator transient simulations need a "kick" in order to start up since the DC operating point is an unstable equilibrium point of the oscillator. In real life, this kick would be provided by noise.

Also, ensure your cross coupled pair provides enough negative resistance to maintain oscillation. By adding the varactors, you have lowered the tank resonance frequency. As a result, the tank resistance on resonance may have dropped, meaning overall loop gain could have dropped.

I was also under the impression that TSMC 65nm pdk was under NDA, so I'm not sure you should be posting this level of detail here.

@LetterSized I have added VCO outputs, I used the transient noise option in ADE to get the transient response. Also what details should I remove from this post? if you could please help me, I am still in university so I didn't know about the NDA stuff

@LetterSized I have removed the earlier images of the schematic which had component values in them, I have added new images which contain only the dc op pt details

Do you have a differential stability analysis around the loop? It should be possible to verify whether Barkhausen's criterion is actually met.

@nanofarad sorry but I don't know what a differential stability analysis is or how to setup one.

Break the feedback loop symmetrically at some point, put an analoglib:diffstbprobe to join the broken ends. The analysis is called stb and takes the probe's name and frequency range as a parameter. Gain and phase can be obtained from Direct Plot -> Main Form (as with other analyses)

I would suspect that the loop gain was marginal to begin with and is insufficient with the varactors, but I can only speculate without real measurements. If you aren't able to get the loop gain measurement for some reason, you may want to at least try increasing the g_m of your cross-coupled pair to try to push the loop gain up - though, again, having real measurements of the loop gain is vital for this sort of project.

@nanofarad thanks for your comment. I was also trying to increase gm by further increasing the tail current source and the device size by increasing number of fingers and that has made it work. I used the negative resistance view as suggested by Lettersized to look at my design and now it seems to be working.

If you've gotten it working and think your question is resolved, I would recommend posting an answer detailing what you did and why (feel free to quote/copy-paste my comments if you'd like), and then marking the question as accepted so that it doesn't show up as "unanswered". With that said, you also now have a good example before/after circuit to try the differential stability analysis and review the results against expectation :)
